# Select Control Populated from JavaScript Returns Empty Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, select, postback

In my ASP.NET applications, I have a server-side HTML select control.

```
<select id="CompanyDropDown" runat="server" style="width:330px">
</select>
```

I then have a link on my page that runs a JavaScript function that populates this control, and also selects the "current" item. I can see this is working because the list has all the items and the correct one is selected.

However, when the page posts back in response to a button click.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveCompany" Text="Save" 
    onclick="btnSaveCompany_Click" />
```

`CompanyDropDown.Value` is empty, and it contains no items. Any suggestions on how I can see the selected value on postback?

(Note: I tried using an ASP.NET DropDown control, but that fails postback validation when the control has items that were added after the page was rendered.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because items added to the list using JavaScript aren't part of the viewstate, they cannot be retrieved server side. If you are only trying to get the selected value, put a server-side hidden field on your page and set its value using JavaScript each time the selection of the drop-down is changed:

**jQuery script**:

```
$('#CompanyDropDown').change(function() {
    $('#inpSelectValue').val($(this).val());
});
```

**Hidden field markup**:

```
<input runat="server" id="inpSelectValue" clientidmode="static" type="hidden" />
```

The value of the hidden field will be carried to the server on post back. Refer to it to retrieve the value of the selected item. Be sure to add `clientidmode="static"` to your drop down as well to keep the rendered id of your controls set to the id you assign in the ASPX page (i.e., `CompanyDropDown` rather than `parentContainer_CompanyDropDown`):

```
<select id="CompanyDropDown" runat="server" style="width:330px"
    clientidmode="static" />
```

---

Alternatively, you could use AJAX to tell the server you are adding each dynamically generated list item or changing the selection. I would only do this if you needed to maintain a list of items in addition to which one is selected.

Comment: @Justin: I can't for the live of me get this to work. I verified my JavaScript routine is getting called and is updating the hidden field correctly. However, on postback, the hidden field has the same value it had when the page was rendered.

Comment: @Justin: Not in markup, but I am initializing the value of the hidden field from server code. Does that prevent the new value from posting back?

Comment: @Jon, No, that shouldn't matter. Are you initializing to something other than blank to make sure that value isn't being set? And are you sure the JavaScript is working correctly? Add `alert($('#inpSelectedValue').val());` to the change method after you set the value.

Comment: @Justin: I've stepped through the JavaScript using the debugger. It is working correctly. I also see I get the value server-side using `Request.Form[HiddenCompanyId.Name]`. It is surely getting set correctly. RE: "Are you initializing to something other than blank...", I'm initializing the hidden field value to "403", it's used by the JavaScript to select the current item when the list is populated.

Comment: @Jon, there's no reason for it to not work. Can you post part of your code?

Comment: I just verified that, if I *don't* initialize the hidden field server-side, then it works. Initializing the hidden field causes any values to be lost. My best guess is that initializing it makes the value become part of viewstate, which restores the initial value after postback. Doesn't make complete sense to me but that's my best explanation for what I'm observing.

Answer (score 1):

The values manipulated in JS can't be retrieved on the server-side and can't be retained on postback. You can put the `SelectedValue` in a hidden field. On page postback you have to set the `SelectedValue` again that you save in the hidden field.

Comment: @Muhammad: Thanks, but even this won't work for me. I verified I'm updating the value of the hidden field correctly. But, on postback, that has also been restored to the value it had when the page was rendered.

Comment: You have update the SelectedValue on Postback before Page Rendering.

Comment: @Muhammad: I'm not setting the SelectedValue on the server. However, I do initialize the hidden field value. Does that prevent the new value from being posted back?

Comment: On server side, when you are trying to Set the SelectedValue, Can you Check the CompanyDropDown.Items.Count ?

Comment: In the markup, CompanyDropDown is defined as `<select id="CompanyDropDown" runat="server" style="width:330px" onchange="UpdateHiddenCompanyId();"></select>`. It's quite empty, I assure you. It only gets populated client-side if a link is clicked.

Comment: yah man, that's what I was thinking, you are trying to set the value on server side, when there is no item in the dropdown, then how can it be possible, you can set the value ? the thing, after postback complete, you need to add list items again, then you can set the SelectedValue in JavaScript.

Comment: @JonathanWood let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1039/discussion-between-muhammad-akhtar-and-jonathan-wood)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request.Form[CompanyDropDown.UniqueID]. This will work without hidden field.

Comment: Not sure why this is not the top answer, it works great without adding extra hidden input and trying to keep the values in sync.